# Change theme color angular2 sass

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular2-template

I will allow a user to choose a theme, basically a set of SASS color variables with the new colors. How would be the best way of going about changing this when the user selects from a drop down
in sass file i have 5 theme files 
how to implement in angular 2

its possible ?

```
@import 'mixins';
@import 'colorSchemes/material';
// @import 'colorSchemes/darktheme';
// @import 'colorSchemes/redtheme';
// @import 'colorSchemes/bluetheme';
// @import 'colorSchemes/greentheme';
@import 'variables';


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleSelect1">Select Theme</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
    <option>material</option>
    <option>darktheme</option>
    <option>redtheme</option>
    <option>bluetheme</option>
    <option>Greentheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You could change the `href` of your stylesheet link element, maybe just with a `ng-ref` will do the trick.

Comment: tried not working

Comment: What strikes to my mind is since that's 5-6 themes you first define the colors for the theme and then you change the color through *ngClass directive according to the theme change. Would like to know if there's a better way than this.